# Angular material Legacy theme from core not updating

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material, responsive-design

I have been upgrading the Angular version and material on the below versions , but still my styles all messed up and design was not like the orignal one, basically i wanted to use the old material design since the angular version upgrade looking the material also to update this looks mess , any help?

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/elements": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^15.0.0-beta.42",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "^16.1.3",
    "@angular/material-luxon-adapter": "^16.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material/tabs": "^2.3.0",
    "document-register-element": "^1.14.10",
    "ics": "^2.35.0",
    "lazysizes": "^5.3.2",
    "luxon": "^3.0.0",
    "material-table": "^1.69.3",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^7.0.2",
    "ngx-link-preview": "^1.1.6",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.13.3"
  },
```

and my Scss file

```
@import '@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();


theme-members-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
theme-members-accent: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
theme-members-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
theme-members-theme: mat-light-theme(theme-members-primary, theme-members-accent, theme-members-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme(theme-members-theme);


.mat-calendar{

  theme-members-primary2: mat-palette($md-fuscia);
  theme-members-theme2: mat-light-theme(theme-members-primary2, theme-members-accent, theme-members-warn);
  // Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
  @include angular-material-theme(theme-members-theme2);



}

// Define a custom typography config that overrides the font-family as well as the
// `headlines` and `body-1` levels.
$typography-configuration: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Barlow',
  $input: mat-typography-level(16px, 1.94, 500),

);

@include angular-material-typography($typography-configuration);
```

I have pointed the legacy in my angular.json file

```
  "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/legacy-prebuilt-themes/legacy-indigo-pink.css", 
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css"
            ],
```